# Suggested synonym for finance → money

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

I'd just like to suggest "money" as a synonym for the "finance" tag.

One of my questions was recently tagged with [finance](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finance), I remember that I did search the tags for "money" but it did not appear. This would solve this problem.

Comment: I like this, if it gets more support I'd be in favor of doing it.

Comment: @Undo to me the two are so much synonym, I'd automatically check for "finance" first when looking for "money": "money" doesn't feel like a tag to me (maybe not abstract enough). One wouldn't use `doctor`/`pills` but rather `health` (or `medicine`) for a tag, right? – But I'm fine with a synonym if it helps. Count my vote as "undecided, but not contra" :)

Comment: Given the questions currently tagged as finance are mostly accounting, I would suggest accounting (or money if needed) rather than finance.

Answer (score 2):

This gets interesting because tags work in a different way than human linguistics.

In linguistics, we have constructs such as supersets, subsets, and overlapping sets.  In contrast, with tags, everything is linear because all tags are at the same *hierarchical level*.

*Finance* topics can include accounting, investing, savings, loans, mortgages, depreciation, budgeting, and more.

*Money* topics can include currency identification, currency conversions, numismatics, finance, and more.

Even though money initially appears to be a superset of finance, in fact, money is a tool used in finance.  It's easy to talk about money without talking about finance, and it's equally easy to talk about finance without talking about money.  On the other hand, talking about finance without talking about *assets* is challenging.  But I think it's safe to say that very few people would use an *assets* tag.

The relationships between these lingual constructs get complicated quite quickly.

Creating SE tags at the appropriate level of detail is challenging, yet important.  If we get very detailed, it becomes easy to find posts, but difficult for people to assign the most appropriate tags.  If we get too general, the tags become fairly useless.

We currently have 41 open (4 closed) QAs with the [finance](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finance) tag and only 9 open QAs (1 closed) with the [accounting](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/accounting) tag.  Some of the ones tagged with [finance](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finance) are accounting questions, and some of the ones tagged with [accounting](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/accounting) are finance questions.  The lines get blurred very quickly.  Using the [accounting](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/accounting) tag will not find all the accounting QAs, and using the [finance](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finance) tag will not find all the finance QAs.

**TL;DR** The bottom line is that we have at least one user who did not find the [finance](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finance) tag, but did think of using *money*.

For Software Recommendations SE, at this time, I think it is a good idea to have a single tag for everything that is finance or money related.  Currently, that is 50 open questions.  This way, users will have a single tag to find all such QAs.

The terms *money*, *accounting*, and *bookkeeping* can then be set as synonyms for [finance](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finance).

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to have tags with a higher degree of granularity.  More granularity makes it less likely that an answer will be included in a "search by tag" operation.  This can make it *harder* to find QAs because they won't be included in the results.  But it can also make it *easier* to find QAs because there will be fewer search results to sift through.

Select this option if you prefer having multiple tags: [finance](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finance), [accounting](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/accounting), and [investing](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/investing)

For this option, *bookkeeping* can be a synonym for [accounting](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/accounting), and *money* can be a synonym for [finance](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finance).